# Places API - Pulling reviews

Tags: google-maps

From everything I've researched, using Places API to pull reviews from a business page listing, I am limited to 5 reviews.  Is there a way to get more than 5 reviews?

Secondly, if there is not a way to get more than 5 reviews is there a way to target the most recent 5 reviews instead of the featured 5 reviews.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is [one of the most popular feature requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/35825957) to have more than 5 reviews returned. You can star the issue to receive updates.